# How to get number of methods in angularjs service?

Tags: angularjs

For `Jasmine` testing purposes, I want a test to fail if the number of methods in the service being tested is different from what is expected. That would tell the programmer that the test fixture is incomplete and that he must make more tests.

How can I ask a service how many methods there are and, if possible, the method names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking but if you can access the service object, 
can't you just iterate over its properties and check their type?

For example with `$http` service you could do:

```
var methods = [];
for (prop in $http){
   if (typeof $http[prop] === "function") {
       methods.push(prop)
   }
}
```

then you have all the method names of your service and you can count them.